# If G is a primitive group action on A, then $G_a$ is a maximal subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If G is a primitive group action on A, then $G_a$ is a maximal subgroup of G

A block is a subset $B \subseteq A$ such that for any $\sigma \in G$, either $\sigma (B) = B$ or $\sigma(B) \cap B = \emptyset$.  A transitive group action is called primitive if the only blocks in $A$ are single elements $a \in A$ or $A$ itself.

I'm having trouble showing that the stabilizer of an element $G_a$ is maximal in $G$.  Its fairly easy to show that $G_a \le G_B$, but moving beyond that point is hard.  I googled and found a site saying that there is a one to one correspendance between blocks countaining $a$ and subgroups containing $G_a$, but I don't see why this is true.

Comment: If $G_a<H<G$, can you show that $Ha$ is a block?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $G_a\subseteq H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup of $G$; let $B=\{ ha\mid h\in H\}$. I claim that $B$ is a block.

Indeed, assume that $x\in B\cap\sigma(B)$. Then there exist $h,h'\in H$ such that $ha = \sigma h'a$. Therefore, $h^{-1}\sigma h' a = a$, so $h^{-1}\sigma h'\in G_a$. Since $G_a\subseteq H$, then $h(h^{-1}\sigma h')h'^{-1}\in H$, so $\sigma\in H$. Therefore, $\sigma(B) = B$, since $B$ is invariant under the action of $H$.

Since $B$ is a block, by the primitivity we know that either $B=\{a\}$ or $B=A$. If $B=\{a\}$, then $ha=a$ for all $h\in H$, so $H\subseteq G_a$, hence $H=G_a$.

If $B=A$, then for every $g\in G$ there exists $h\in H$ such that $ga = ha$ (by transitivity of the action); hence $h^{-1}ga = a$, so $h^{-1}g\in G_a\subseteq H$; hence $g\in H$. This proves that $G\subseteq H$, so $H=G$.

In summary, if the action is primitive, $a\in A$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $G_a\subseteq H\subseteq G$, then $G_a=H$ or $H=G$. That is, $G_a$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In your second paragraph, you assume that $x \in B \cap \sigma(B)$ where, presumably, $\sigma$ in $G$ is arbitrary. Then you proceed to conclude that $\sigma H$. Why wouldn't we be finished at that point, since you proved that $G \subseteq H$?

Comment: @user193319: $\sigma$ is not an arbitrary element of $G$. It is an element of $G$ *with the property* that $B\cap \sigma(B)$ is nonempty. So we are not proving that $G\subseteq H$, we are proving that $\{\sigma\in G\mid B\cap\sigma(B)\neq\varnothing\}\subseteq H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How transitivity is used in this proof? I think transitivity is required to prove the opposite inclusion of the given statement only, in your proof in the fourth para you mentioned the use of transitivity but I didn't get the use of transitivity there, rather it is the use of the assumption A=B, am I right?

Comment: @chenu: If only you had waited three weeks, you could have been following up on a 10 year old post, instead of a 9-years-11-months-and-one-week post. I am going to have to review the thing from scratch, because I cannot possibly remember what was going on (almost) ten years ago.

Comment: @chenu: The assumption of transitivity is used to conclude that either $B=\{a\}$ or $B=A$. Namely, we are using that all blocks have the same size, and that the original action is primitive (which requires transitivity).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Still I didn't get the point. Can you please, elaborate on the explanation?

Comment: @chenu: To even talk about primitivity you need transitivity. It is a pre-requisite. Primitivity is used to conclude that the only possible blocks are the singletons and the whole thing. If you don't have transitivity, then you can't even talk about primitivity.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Got it. Thank you